# Powerpoint : logging who opened the file

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I created a powerpoint presentation.
I'm gonna send it to a lot of people but I would like to know exactly who opened the file.

Importate note: the slides are sent by mail. No web-hosting.

Is there anyway to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: One answer is to send a link to the file, which you locate on a web-site. You can then apply any access credentials you choose for down-loading the file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is send by email... not hosting on a website.

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://www.yesware.com/blog/attachment-tracking-know-happens-click-send/

Comment: I assumed it was sent by e-mail: what I suggested that you send a web link in the e-mail instead of an attachment. Sorry if I wasn't clear.